# Thumbnail for ImageField in django model, override save

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a thumbnail from ImageField and save it to my model. I am using this as reference: http://www.yilmazhuseyin.com/blog/dev/create-thumbnails-imagefield-django/

Files are created correctly, I get no errors but fields are not saved in model.
I think i could messed things up in save method. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
def get_avatar_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'avatars/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.id, filename)


class User(AbstractUser):
    # First Name and Last Name do not cover name patterns
    # around the globe.
    name = models.CharField(_('Name of User'), blank=True, max_length=255)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_avatar_path, blank=True)
    small_avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_avatar_path,
                                     blank=True)

    def create_thumbnail(self):
        # If there is no image associated with this.
        # do not create thumbnail
        if not self.avatar:
            return

        # Set our max thumbnail size in a tuple (max width, max height)
        THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (200, 200)

        DJANGO_TYPE = self.avatar.file.content_type
        print DJANGO_TYPE

        if DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/jpeg':
            PIL_TYPE = 'jpeg'
            FILE_EXTENSION = 'jpg'
        elif DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/png':
            PIL_TYPE = 'png'
            FILE_EXTENSION = 'png'
        elif DJANGO_TYPE == 'image/gif':
            PIL_TYPE = 'gif'
            FILE_EXTENSION = 'gif'

        # Open original photo which we want to thumbnail using PIL's Image
        image = Image.open(StringIO(self.avatar.read()))

        # use our PIL Image object to create the thumbnail, which already
        image.thumbnail(THUMBNAIL_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)

        # Save the thumbnail
        temp_handle = StringIO()
        image.save(temp_handle, PIL_TYPE)
        temp_handle.seek(0)

        # Save image to a SimpleUploadedFile which can be saved into ImageField
        print os.path.split(self.avatar.name)[-1]
        suf = SimpleUploadedFile(os.path.split(self.avatar.name)[-1],
                                 temp_handle.read(), content_type=DJANGO_TYPE)
        # Save SimpleUploadedFile into image field
        print os.path.splitext(suf.name)[0]
        self.small_avatar.save(
            '%s_thumbnail.%s' % (os.path.splitext(suf.name)[0], FILE_EXTENSION),
            suf, save=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.create_thumbnail()
        super(User, self).save()
```

Comment: You mean file created in the folder but the record not save in DB?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Both fields: avatar and small_avatar are empty.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. It surely saves the `avatar` and `small_avatar`. What do you mean by `fields are not saved in model`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for feedback. Sorry for newbie problems, I am a beginner developer.
Problem seems to be resolved by invalidating caches, restarting IDE and services.
In my opinion code above should be persisted as some of solutions on the web are outdated.